# If using dual sim on Huawei P20 Pro would changing sims show in either Google Activity or Huawei Data Download

Tags: google, huawei, dual-sim, huawei-p20

I have a Huawei P20 Pro with dual sim capability. If I used (signed into) the second sim with another Google account, would My Google Activity on the Google account of the first sim show the switch, backwards and forwards, between the two sims? OR if not.. Would the switch be shown on the Huawei download data for my phone, if at all?

Comment: What do you mean with "Huawei download data"?

Comment: Hi Robert, sorry if I was vague. I meant the personal data that can be requested and downloaded from HUAWEI through Data Management in Manage Your Privacy in the Account Centre on a HUAWEI phone.

Comment: I do not own a Huawei device, hence I don't know what is recorded. But if it tracks your IP address (and changes of that) or the used MNO/IMEI for mobile data, switching between SIM1 and SIM2 should result in an IP address change. However enabling/disabling Wifi or entering an area with a configured Wifi would also trigger an IP address change.

Comment: I never thought of that. Thank you Robert.

Answer (score 0):

Google accounts are independent of the SIM card, you just need Internet for accessing Google. If this happens on your device with SIM1, SIM2 or Wifi is irrelevant to Google.

Note: Usually in dual-SIM Smartphone only one SIM can be active for Internet access at a time.